# In Pages 5, how to get a table to span multiple pages?

Tags: pages

I have a two-column table in a document in Pages 5. The table starts mid-way down a page with content above it.

When I add rows to the table, if there isn't enough room to fit the entire table on the same page, the *entire* table jumps to the next page, leaving a big empty gap in the document.

How do I get Pages to instead start the table at the original page, and span the table onto the next page instead?

Answer (score 4):

Looks like it happens because "Prevent widow & orphan lines" option is activated by default.

Select the text where the table is located, in the Inspector panel look for "**More**" and uncheck "**Prevent widow & orphan lines**". I had the same problem and found the solution this [Apple Support Communities thread](http://discussions.apple.com/thread/6603867).

Answer (score 2):

As of Pages 6.3.1 it looks like the situation has got worse!

Within tables there is no "Prevent widow & orphan lines" option in the More tab. It's still there in normal text.

And if a table cell exceeds page limits it's simply truncated and there's no way I can see to recover the text.

Comment: @Scot This looks like an answer to me ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Still Pages 7.3 has this issue... :(